# Is it possible to relink gcc binaries with musl-gcc?

Tags: linux, gcc, cgo, musl-gcc

I am building a Linux Go 21.1.1 app that is using 3rd party C libraries. It works on my dev system (22.04) but fails on some other dists with glibc problems. It seemed a reasonable alternative is to statically link everything with musl-gcc. But I think the 3rd party libraries are still looking for glibc and it's causing conflicts.

Is it possible to force the linker to relink everything? I really am not sure how to solve this. It seems to be using both...

```
env CC=/usr/bin/musl-gcc \
    CGO_FLAGS="-I/usr/include/X86_64-linux-musl" \
go build -a \
    -o $DIST/$PROG \
    -ldflags "-v -s -X 'main.Version=$VER' -linkmode external -extldflags '-static'"
```

produces this... systray is the 3rd party library.

```
# github.com/getlantern/systray
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-musl/errno.h:10,
                 from cgo-gcc-prolog:30:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/errno.h:26:11: fatal error: linux/errno.h: No such file or directory
   26 | # include <linux/errno.h>
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

If I just compile it with gcc, it works fine on some but fails on other dists. e.g. Debian 11 gives:

```
/usr/local/bin/myagent 
/usr/local/bin/myagent: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/myagent)
/usr/local/bin/myagent: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/myagent)
111
```

Any and all ideas are welcome!